# How to modify open-cv for-android to run it in portriat mode

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on an android App which detects faces and show counts on screen. Here is its screen-short.[image] 
For face detection I used open-cv-for-android library, but it runs in landscape mode and it is working very well. I want App should run in portrait mode and detect faces properly. I searched this problem on google and followed this post

[OpenCV camera orientation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669779/opencv-camera-orientation-issue)

but I got this error :

[image]

Here is open-cv-java code

```
package org.opencv.android;
import java.util.List; 
import org.opencv.R;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * This is a basic class, implementing the interaction with Camera and OpenCV library.
 * The main responsibility of it - is to control when camera can be enabled, process the frame,
 * call external listener to make any adjustments to the frame and then draw the resulting
 * frame to the screen.
 * The clients shall implement CvCameraViewListener.
 */
public abstract class CameraBridgeViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraBridge";
    private static final int MAX_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
    private static final int STOPPED = 0;
    private static final int STARTED = 1;

    private int mState = STOPPED;
    private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
    private CvCameraViewListener2 mListener;
    private boolean mSurfaceExist;
    private Object mSyncObject = new Object();

    protected int mFrameWidth;
    protected int mFrameHeight;
    protected int mMaxHeight;
    protected int mMaxWidth;
    protected float mScale = 0;
    protected int mPreviewFormat = RGBA;
    protected int mCameraIndex = CAMERA_ID_ANY;
    protected boolean mEnabled;
    protected FpsMeter mFpsMeter = null;

    public static final int CAMERA_ID_ANY   = -1;
    public static final int CAMERA_ID_BACK  = 99;
    public static final int CAMERA_ID_FRONT = 98;
    public static final int RGBA = 1;
    public static final int GRAY = 2;

    public CameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, int cameraId) {
        super(context);
        mCameraIndex = cameraId;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
        mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    public CameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        int count = attrs.getAttributeCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Attr count: " + Integer.valueOf(count));

        TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase);
        if (styledAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_show_fps, false))
            enableFpsMeter();

        mCameraIndex = styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_camera_id, -1);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
        mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
        styledAttrs.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the camera index
     * @param cameraIndex new camera index
     */
    public void setCameraIndex(int cameraIndex) {
        this.mCameraIndex = cameraIndex;
    }

    public interface CvCameraViewListener {
        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
         * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
         * @param width -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
         * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
         */
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height);

        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
         * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
         */
        public void onCameraViewStopped();

        /**
         * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
         * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
         * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
         */
        public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame);
    }

    public interface CvCameraViewListener2 {
        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
         * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
         * @param width -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
         * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
         */
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height);

        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
         * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
         */
        public void onCameraViewStopped();

        /**
         * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
         * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
         * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
         */
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame);
    };

    protected class CvCameraViewListenerAdapter implements CvCameraViewListener2  {
        public CvCameraViewListenerAdapter(CvCameraViewListener oldStypeListener) {
            mOldStyleListener = oldStypeListener;
        }

        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
            mOldStyleListener.onCameraViewStarted(width, height);
        }

        public void onCameraViewStopped() {
            mOldStyleListener.onCameraViewStopped();
        }

        public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
             Mat result = null;
             switch (mPreviewFormat) {
                case RGBA:
                    result = mOldStyleListener.onCameraFrame(inputFrame.rgba());
                    break;
                case GRAY:
                    result = mOldStyleListener.onCameraFrame(inputFrame.gray());
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid frame format! Only RGBA and Gray Scale are supported!");
            };

            return result;
        }

        public void setFrameFormat(int format) {
            mPreviewFormat = format;
        }

        private int mPreviewFormat = RGBA;
        private CvCameraViewListener mOldStyleListener;
    };

    /**
     * This class interface is abstract representation of single frame from camera for onCameraFrame callback
     * Attention: Do not use objects, that represents this interface out of onCameraFrame callback!
     */
    public interface CvCameraViewFrame {

        /**
         * This method returns RGBA Mat with frame
         */
        public Mat rgba();

        /**
         * This method returns single channel gray scale Mat with frame
         */
        public Mat gray();
    };

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call surfaceChanged event");
        synchronized(mSyncObject) {
            if (!mSurfaceExist) {
                mSurfaceExist = true;
                checkCurrentState();
            } else {
                /** Surface changed. We need to stop camera and restart with new parameters */
                /* Pretend that old surface has been destroyed */
                mSurfaceExist = false;
                checkCurrentState();
                /* Now use new surface. Say we have it now */
                mSurfaceExist = true;
                checkCurrentState();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        /* Do nothing. Wait until surfaceChanged delivered */
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        synchronized(mSyncObject) {
            mSurfaceExist = false;
            checkCurrentState();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is provided for clients, so they can enable the camera connection.
     * The actual onCameraViewStarted callback will be delivered only after both this method is called and surface is available
     */
    public void enableView() {
        synchronized(mSyncObject) {
            mEnabled = true;
            checkCurrentState();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is provided for clients, so they can disable camera connection and stop
     * the delivery of frames even though the surface view itself is not destroyed and still stays on the scren
     */
    public void disableView() {
        synchronized(mSyncObject) {
            mEnabled = false;
            checkCurrentState();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method enables label with fps value on the screen
     */
    public void enableFpsMeter() {
        if (mFpsMeter == null) {
            mFpsMeter = new FpsMeter();
            mFpsMeter.setResolution(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
        }
    }

    public void disableFpsMeter() {
            mFpsMeter = null;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param listener
     */

    public void setCvCameraViewListener(CvCameraViewListener2 listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setCvCameraViewListener(CvCameraViewListener listener) {
        CvCameraViewListenerAdapter adapter = new CvCameraViewListenerAdapter(listener);
        adapter.setFrameFormat(mPreviewFormat);
        mListener = adapter;
    }

    /**
     * This method sets the maximum size that camera frame is allowed to be. When selecting
     * size - the biggest size which less or equal the size set will be selected.
     * As an example - we set setMaxFrameSize(200,200) and we have 176x152 and 320x240 sizes. The
     * preview frame will be selected with 176x152 size.
     * This method is useful when need to restrict the size of preview frame for some reason (for example for video recording)
     * @param maxWidth - the maximum width allowed for camera frame.
     * @param maxHeight - the maximum height allowed for camera frame
     */
    public void setMaxFrameSize(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        mMaxWidth = maxWidth;
        mMaxHeight = maxHeight;
    }

    public void SetCaptureFormat(int format)
    {
        mPreviewFormat = format;
        if (mListener instanceof CvCameraViewListenerAdapter) {
            CvCameraViewListenerAdapter adapter = (CvCameraViewListenerAdapter) mListener;
            adapter.setFrameFormat(mPreviewFormat);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when mSyncObject lock is held
     */
    private void checkCurrentState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "call checkCurrentState");
        int targetState;

        if (mEnabled && mSurfaceExist && getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
            targetState = STARTED;
        } else {
            targetState = STOPPED;
        }

        if (targetState != mState) {
            /* The state change detected. Need to exit the current state and enter target state */
            processExitState(mState);
            mState = targetState;
            processEnterState(mState);
        }
    }

    private void processEnterState(int state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call processEnterState: " + state);
        switch(state) {
        case STARTED:
            onEnterStartedState();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onCameraViewStarted(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
            }
            break;
        case STOPPED:
            onEnterStoppedState();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onCameraViewStopped();
            }
            break;
        };
    }

    private void processExitState(int state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "call processExitState: " + state);
        switch(state) {
        case STARTED:
            onExitStartedState();
            break;
        case STOPPED:
            onExitStoppedState();
            break;
        };
    }

    private void onEnterStoppedState() {
        /* nothing to do */
    }

    private void onExitStoppedState() {
        /* nothing to do */
    }

    // NOTE: The order of bitmap constructor and camera connection is important for android 4.1.x
    // Bitmap must be constructed before surface
    private void onEnterStartedState() {
        Log.d(TAG, "call onEnterStartedState");
        /* Connect camera */
        if (!connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight())) {
            AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
            ad.setMessage("It seems that you device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed.");
            ad.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,  "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
                }
            });
            ad.show();

        }
    }

    private void onExitStartedState() {
        disconnectCamera();
        if (mCacheBitmap != null) {
            mCacheBitmap.recycle();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method shall be called by the subclasses when they have valid
     * object and want it to be delivered to external client (via callback) and
     * then displayed on the screen.
     * @param frame - the current frame to be delivered
     */
    protected void deliverAndDrawFrame(CvCameraViewFrame frame) {
        Mat modified;

        if (mListener != null) {
            modified = mListener.onCameraFrame(frame);
        } else {
            modified = frame.rgba();
        }

        boolean bmpValid = true;
        if (modified != null) {
            try {
                Utils.matToBitmap(modified, mCacheBitmap);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Mat type: " + modified);
                Log.e(TAG, "Bitmap type: " + mCacheBitmap.getWidth() + "*" + mCacheBitmap.getHeight());
                Log.e(TAG, "Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: " + e.getMessage());
                bmpValid = false;
            }
        }

        if (bmpValid && mCacheBitmap != null) {
            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(0, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                Log.d(TAG, "mStretch value: " + mScale);

                if (mScale != 0) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, new Rect(0,0,mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight()),
                            new Rect((int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2),
                                    (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2),
                                    (int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + mScale*mCacheBitmap.getWidth()),
                                    (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + mScale*mCacheBitmap.getHeight())), null);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mCacheBitmap, new Rect(0,0,mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight()),
                            new Rect((canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2,
                                    (canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2,
                                    (canvas.getWidth() - mCacheBitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + mCacheBitmap.getWidth(),
                                    (canvas.getHeight() - mCacheBitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + mCacheBitmap.getHeight()), null);
                }

                if (mFpsMeter != null) {
                    mFpsMeter.measure();
                    mFpsMeter.draw(canvas, 20, 30);
                }
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked shall perform concrete operation to initialize the camera.
     * CONTRACT: as a result of this method variables mFrameWidth and mFrameHeight MUST be
     * initialized with the size of the Camera frames that will be delivered to external processor.
     * @param width - the width of this SurfaceView
     * @param height - the height of this SurfaceView
     */
    protected abstract boolean connectCamera(int width, int height);

    /**
     * Disconnects and release the particular camera object being connected to this surface view.
     * Called when syncObject lock is held
     */
    protected abstract void disconnectCamera();

    // NOTE: On Android 4.1.x the function must be called before SurfaceTexture constructor!
    protected void AllocateCache()
    {
        mCacheBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    public interface ListItemAccessor {
        public int getWidth(Object obj);
        public int getHeight(Object obj);
    };

    /**
     * This helper method can be called by subclasses to select camera preview size.
     * It goes over the list of the supported preview sizes and selects the maximum one which
     * fits both values set via setMaxFrameSize() and surface frame allocated for this view
     * @param supportedSizes
     * @param surfaceWidth
     * @param surfaceHeight
     * @return optimal frame size
     */
    protected Size calculateCameraFrameSize(List<?> supportedSizes, ListItemAccessor accessor, int surfaceWidth, int surfaceHeight) {
        int calcWidth = 0;
        int calcHeight = 0;

        int maxAllowedWidth = (mMaxWidth != MAX_UNSPECIFIED && mMaxWidth < surfaceWidth)? mMaxWidth : surfaceWidth;
        int maxAllowedHeight = (mMaxHeight != MAX_UNSPECIFIED && mMaxHeight < surfaceHeight)? mMaxHeight : surfaceHeight;

        for (Object size : supportedSizes) {
            int width = accessor.getWidth(size);
            int height = accessor.getHeight(size);

            if (width <= maxAllowedWidth && height <= maxAllowedHeight) {
                if (width >= calcWidth && height >= calcHeight) {
                    calcWidth = (int) width;
                    calcHeight = (int) height;
                }
            }
        }

        return new Size(calcWidth, calcHeight);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you think you could provide a [mcve] question and shorten the code? Please provide just as few code as needed to understand and solve your problem. I doubt that someone will go through that huge code novel.

Comment: @L. Guthardt its complete and could not reduce the length of post to fully convey our problem.

Comment: Ok, if you are sure that all this code is required leave the question as it is. But just as a note, the more unclear a question is, not due to formatting issues, ... but due to vast code, it makes a question way less  attractive. So you won't get that much potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

All I could see in your code is that:

```
            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
```

On this line you may not be getting right canvas object, put it in try-catch block and try to debug it on this point you might find the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still generating same error; have you tested this code?

Comment: I'd need a little more info to test this code, can you share the activity class in which you're using this?

Comment: Thanks for your response i did not know how to share activity. I am not able to attach file in this comment.

Comment: Ok, Last thing Try:  Canvas canvas = getApplicationContext().getHolder().lockCanvas(); Hope this helps

Comment: Here is link to same post which has activity class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361672/how-to-change-screen-orientation-from-landscape-to-portrait

Comment: Check this answer, people have the faced similar issue. This might solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897200/5428672